# Is there a way to "re-advertise" a question after a major edit?

Tags: discussion, bumping

A week ago, I asked a question on MathSE. It did not get any answers (I even won a tumbleweed badge because of it), so today I rewrote it completely, to make the problem more "accessible" ([the question is here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202375/calculating-sum-y-0x-pry-y-prz-leq-k-y2-when-y-z-are-binomially-d)).

Is there a way to make the SE-system aware of a major rewrite, so that users see it just like a new question. It would not be nice to have it forgotten completely?

Comment: Most users come to the site and see the "Active questions" tab, meaning that any edit will bring it back to the front page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Editing bumps a question to the frontpage again, so you get some exposure from the edit alone. The only other way to get more attention is to put up a bounty, but you don't have enough reputation yet to do that.

Comment: Well, you can also advertise the question on chat. Technically, there are lots of ways to advertise a question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Asking on the chat seemed to create some upvotes, so hopefully it will create interest among knowledgable people :-)

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker There's a rather thin line between carefully mentioning an overlooked question on chat and spamming chat with your own questions. I didn't want to explicitly advertise this solution, as I can't know if it will be used responsibly or not.

Comment: You could take out an ad in the local newspaper.  Craigs List would work.